# Randomly generate a line from a .txt file

Tags: python, random, printing, words

I'm rather new to python and have been set an assignment. I need to randomly generate a word from a .txt file. I can retrieve specific lines, such a get line 2, or line 5, however I want to randomly generate what line is retrieved.

This is what I currently have

```
input("Press Enter to continue...")

with open('words.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if i == 1:
         break
print (line)
```

I tried doing this but it just came up with randrange is not defined

```
input("Press Enter to continue...")

import random
with open('words.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, randrange(1,14)):
        if i == 1:
         break
print (line)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it didn't work" ? Can you share the desired output and the actual output ?

Comment: and the traceback if there is one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select one line at random from a file:

```
import random
with open('/etc/passwd') as f:
    print (random.choice(list(f)))
```

To select an arbitrary line from a file, say the *i*-th line:

```
with open('/etc/passwd') as f:
    print (list(f)[i])
```

Or, this might be more efficient:

```
import itertools
with open('/etc/passwd') as f:
    print (next(itertools.islice(f, i, i+1)))
```

However, the "simplest, and almost certainly most efficient, way to select an arbitrary line from a file is `linecache.getline('/etc/password', i)`."  – [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert)

Comment: Invalid Syntax is all I get

Comment: Oh, you use python3. Just a moment. There, that should fix it.

Comment: The simplest, and almost certainly most efficient, way to select an arbitrary line from a file is `linecache.getline('/etc/password', i)`.

Comment: I haven't seen [`linecache`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Sorry my school use python 3 so I thought it would be easier using it at home

Comment: Now this is working, would it be possible to retrieve the line, which is a single word, and set it to a definition?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Perhaps replace the print statement with `the_line = random.choice(list(f))` ?

Comment: Yes that's it, it amazes me how simple and obvious it all is, yet I keep missing it every time, I need practise, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

`import random` doesn't cause `randrange` to become defined; it causes `random` to become defined, and the `random` module has a function named `randrange` in it, so you can do this:

```
for i, line in enumerate(f, random.randrange(1,14)):
```

Or, alternatively, you can `from random import randrange`.

See the tutorial chapter on [Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) for more information.

Once you fix this, your code will work, but your algorithm isn't actually correct.

Let's say `randrange` returns `7`. `enumerate(f, 7)` returns the first line of the file and the number 7 then the second line and the number 8, and so on. So `i` will never be `1`, and you'll never print anything.

To make this work, you need to compare `i` to the random number. Like this:

```
line_number = random.randrange(1, 14)
for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i == line_number:
        break
```

Of course this still only picks a random line in the range [1, 14), not any line in the file. And, if the file is too short, it will be heavily weight to the last line.

So what you *really* need to do is get the count of lines, then pick a random number in `randrange(count_of_lines)`, then use that. But you can't get the count of lines without reading through the whole file. At which point you'd have to close it and read through it all over again to get the one you want. (Although [`linecache`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) might be helpful there.) That's all pretty complicated. So, if you've got enough memory to read in the whole file into a `list`, it makes more sense to just do that, then pick a line from the list, as in Robᵩ's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding the now-needed close parenthesis before the : at the end of your `for` statement.